# Postgresql: Max connections: set application name eating connections

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, thingworx

many connections in PostgreSQL that eating connections limit, many of them named: PostgreSQL JDBC Driver, with a query: SET application_name = 'PostgreSQL JDBC Driver', please find attached image.

causing: FATAL: sorry, too many clients already.
max connections were 100, and I have increased to 150, but not solved!

note that I am using ThingWorx platform which connects to PostgreSQL.

[image: postgresql sessions]

Comment: You are apparently not releasing your connections properly in your Java code.

Comment: till now I am not using a code, just PgAdmin4.

Comment: pgAdmin doesn't use JDBC, so there must be a Java program somwhere that opens those connections

Comment: I am using ThingWorx platform which connects to PostgreSQL, but I didn't found how the platform creating sessions!

Answer (score 1):

if the connection property **"assumeMinServerVersion"** is set to at least 9.0 then the application_name will be set just in the start up packet

```
jdbc:postgresql://<db_address>:5432/<db_name>?assumeMinServerVersion=9.4
```